# How to resize a table cell using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a 2 cells table and I wanna make the first resizable with a grab hand using jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also recommend to use jQuery UI Resizable with some enhancements. I could make it running with valid HTML, updating the table's COLGROUP area on resize. I described the full solution at http://ihofmann.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/resizable-table-columns-with-jquery-ui/

The short one would be:

1) The HTML table specifies the initial width in its COLGROUP area and has CSS property table-layout:fixed.
2) Decorate TH elements with jQuery UI’s .resizable().
3) On resizing start: Find the matching COL element of active TH and remember original width.
4) On resizing: Calculate the resize delta and update (increase/decrease) the selected COL element. This will resize the whole column with every browser.

```
$(".resizable th").resizable({
 handles: "e",

 // set correct COL element and original size
 start: function(event, ui) {
   var colIndex = ui.helper.index() + 1;
   colElement = table.find("colgroup > col:nth-child(" +
   colIndex + ")");

   // get col width (faster than .width() on IE)
   colWidth = parseInt(colElement.get(0).style.width, 10);
   originalSize = ui.size.width;
 },

 // set COL width
 resize: function(event, ui) {
   var resizeDelta = ui.size.width - originalSize;

   var newColWidth = colWidth + resizeDelta;
   colElement.width(newColWidth);

   // height must be set in order to prevent IE9 to set wrong height
   $(this).css("height", "auto");
 }
});
```

Comment: It is better if you repost part of your blog here, rather than just posting the link.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI has a [resizable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) that will allow you to make an element on a page resizable.

However, I can imagine resizing table cells is going to be interesting, especially since they're going to likely share space in a row. Take a look at the [`alsoResize`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-alsoResize) option; you may very well need to scale down the other cell while the other scales up and vice versa.

Also, the IEs are notorious when it comes to manipulating `table` elements, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to do this to a "vanilla" html table.  However, I'm currently using the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) jQuery plugin to provide richer data tables on my page.  It includes (among other things) click-and-drag resizing of column widths.